# MySQL not fetching correct data? (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

This is pretty straight forward.
EDIT:  Updated question and added fourth echo.

Here is PHP code:

```
<?php

$ratings="3";
$item="Inception";

$query="SELECT * FROM items WHERE item = '". $item ."' LIMIT 1";

echo $query;

echo "<br />";

$result=mysql_query($query);

echo $result;

echo "<br />";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $item_id = $row['item_id'];
    echo $item_id;
    echo "<br />";
 }  

  $query_two = "INSERT INTO ratings (rating, item_id), VALUES (' {$ratings} ', ' {$item_id} ')";

  echo $query_two;
  $sql = mysql_query($query_two);
  mysql_close();
?>
```

Here is web output with all the echo's:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE item = 'Inception' LIMIT 1
Resource id #7


INSERT INTO ratings (rating, item_id), VALUES (' 3 ', ' ')
```

How come my $item_id is blank? (third row underneath Resource id)

Comment: That resource is from `echo $result;`, what did you think would happen there?

Comment: I was asking question from the wrong angle. And just answered my own question.  Why is $items_id blank?  because it should be $item_id -- a typo.  But everyone did answer my original question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This part of code produces it:

```
$result=mysql_query($query);

echo $result;
```

It shows `Resource...` because it is of [resource](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) type, it's just a sort of special handler for query, it's not like normal type (string or int for example), so it has nothing readable to print.

If you want to print data from query then you must firstly fetch it.

Also note that those `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, it is discouraged to use them. Note from php manual:

> Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL
>   extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and
>   related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function
>   include:
>
> mysqli_query()
>
> PDO::query()

Answer (score 4):

This does not have anything to do with IDs from the database.

This (`Result#7`) says that this result resource is seventh resource to be created by your php script execution.

Answer (score 3):

Also

```
$query_two = "INSERT INTO ratings (rating, item_id), VALUES (' {$ratings} ', ' {$item_id} ')";
```

should be

```
$query_two = "INSERT INTO ratings (rating, item_id) VALUES (' {$ratings} ', ' {$item_id} ')";
```

You have **comma** before `VALUES`.

Also, it seems that `$item_id` is blank. Please check DB whether you have data for `item = 'Inception'`.

Regarding, `Result#7` please follow others answers.

Comment: Another possible reason for the blank `item_id`: there may be no rows matching the query condition.

Answer (score 2):

The Resource ID is coming from the actual process/object that the MySQL Query is.

to return the result you need:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $query );

echo $row['item']
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something with the result resource.  Try this:

```
$result=mysql_query($query);

//echo $result;

$result_array = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );

print_r( $result_array );
```

**EDIT:** I see you updated your question.

You should run your `item='Inception'` query directly in MySQL to confirm that results are what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot echo the result that simple. You need to fetch the result to for example an array:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  echo $row['a_column'] . "<br />";
}
```

or an object:

```
while ($variable = mysql_fetch_object($query) {
 $value = $variable->a_column;
}
echo $value;
```

There are more ways but this is just two examples